# Compiling GDCM dlls 2.8.4 for Windows with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdcm

I am trying to compile GDCM 2.8.4 for Windows. Can anybody describe how to compile it with Visual Studio 2013 Professional? The GDCM wiki is out of date. Thanks a lot.

Comment: GDCM wiki is even offline at the moment :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will have to install CMake. Then

1. Start CMake GUI.
2. I guess you already have the gdcm-2.8.4 directory (in a directory X:\XXXXX\ ) containing

   Applications
   Source
   Testing
   Utilities

   and other subdirs. So set the in the CMake GUI "**source dir**" to X:\XXXXX\gdcm-2.8.4 . (NOT to its Source subdir!).
3. Then you **create** a **new** directory, where CMake will create the VS projects, let's call it X:\XXXXXX\GDCM-VSProjects. In the CMake GUI set "Where to build the binaries" to X:\XXXXXX\GDCM-VSProjects.
4. Then, in the CMake GUI press "**Configure**".
5. After configuring CMake offers you some options; choose at least GDCM_BUILD_APPLICATIONS, GDCM_BUILD_EXAMPLES, GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS. For documentation you will need doxygen, latex and possibly more.
6. Then, in the CMake GUI press "**Generate**". Now a lengthy calculation is performed and finally VS solution and VS subprojects are generated into your new X:\XXXXXX\GDCM-VSProjects subdirectory.
7. Now you can **open GDCM.sln in VisualStudio** and BuildAll in 64 bit Release mode.
8. After the build, you will find libs, dlls and exes in the bin/Release subdirectory of your X:\XXXXXX\GDCM-VSProjects.

Thats it.